# ndiswrapper error

Tags: wireless, ndiswrapper

I am trying to install `ndiswrapper` with the command `sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper`
and I get the "unable to locate package" error.

I run Ubuntu 12.10 and I do not have an internet connection atm on that laptop.
I have downloaded the `ndiswrapper` package, which is in `/home/x/Downloads/`.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Which package did you download? Not the tar.gz, we hope!

Answer (score 2):

By default, `apt-get` tries to download the package from the repositories. You should instead do it with `dpkg`, like:

`sudo dpkg -i /home/x/Downloads/ndiswrapper.deb`

If the package file name is different from `ndiswrapper.deb` change the command accordingly.

Or you can simply double click on the `.deb` file -- this will open the Software Centre and there you just need to click "Install".